# Partition an array in two groups while keeping the relative order within both groups

Tags: algorithms, mergesort, ordering

I came across the following problem in the book "Elements of Programming Interviews in Python".

> Given an array A of n objects with Boolean-valued keys, reorder the array so that objects that have the key false appear first. The relative ordering of objects with key $true$ should not change. Use $O(1)$ additional space and $O(n)$ times.

My question is, is there an algorithm with $O(1)$ additional space and $O(n)$ time to keep the relative ordering for element with $true$ AND $false$ keys? If so, what is the algorithm? If not, how can I prove it is not possible?

The algorithms I could think about were either $O(n^2)$ or used $O(n)$ additional space.

Comment: @greybread The block quote has the original question, and mine relates to the revised version (both stable). I included the original in the block quote before asking my question. Should I remove the original question?

Comment: No, currently I think the edit helps avoiding misinterpretation. It may be even better to change the wording though - *For the related problem of* stable bipartition, *is there an algorithm with O(1) additional space and O(n) time, keeping the relative ordering for elements with* true *keys as well as those with* false *keys?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such an algorithm.  Hint:

> Scan from right to left (from the end of the array towards the front).

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for both stable, but I provide the solution for the original book problem.

$false$ stable: let $i = 0$, go through every element from left to right, and each time we see a $false$ element, swap it to index $i$, and increment $i$.

$true$ stable: let $i = n - 1$, go through every element from right to left, and each time we see a $true$ element, swap it to index $i$, and decrement $i$.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to prove that there is no solution for both stable?

Comment: @R.Javid honestly I lack experience in that arena, I can only guess that you can't preserve both information during a swap, and you lose information when you don't have auxiliary space

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

$$\color{blue}1\color{blue}2\color{red}3\color{blue}4\color{red}5\color{blue}6\color{red}7\color{red}8\color{blue}9$$

$$\color{blue}1\color{blue}2\color{red}3\color{blue}4\color{red}5\color{red}8\color{red}7\color{blue}6\color{blue}9$$

$$\color{blue}1\color{blue}2\color{red}3\color{red}7\color{red}5\color{red}8\color{blue}4\color{blue}6\color{blue}9$$

$$\cdots$$

Comment: The relative order of reds has changed here.